# Unit test to check if array is reversed

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I have the following code and I am trying to write a Jasmine unit test that will check if the array is reversed. I have created a fiddle with my attempt and can see what is wrong, the current test is checking if it is equal but I want to be specific and check if it is reversed. What is the correct way to implement this?

http://jsfiddle.net/37qnmahk/4/

Code:

```
    $scope.reverse = function(array) {
        var copy = [].concat(array);
        return copy.reverse();
    };
```

Unit test:

```
describe('reverse', function() {
    it('passes if array is reversed', function() {
        var arr = [1, 2, 3];
        scope.reverse();
        scope.$digest();
        expect(arr).toEqual([3, 2, 1]);
    });
});
```

Comment: inject the $controller in unit test function, then instantiate the controller and use your reverse function in expect assertion

Answer (score 1):

Actually in the test, after declaring the array, you should call your reverse function.

```
describe('reverse', function() {
    it('passes if array is reversed', function() {
        var arr = [1, 2, 3];
        //call your reverse function here
        expect(arr).toEqual([3, 2, 1]);
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi, I've update my question to include your suggestion but my test still fails, any idea why?

Comment: The `scope` is undefined. You haven't declared it. Actually what you have to do is something like this:

Comment: Sorry @Szkita couldn't see the rest of what you planned to show

Comment: Sorry :) I updated your fiddle to how it should look like. Hope it helps!

Comment: I made another update on [your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/37qnmahk/8/), according to the [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing) this is the correct way, and it is also easier to understand than my last update.

Comment: If this solved your problem please accept the answer! :)

Comment: Hi, It helped but didn't solve the problem, that is why I did accept.  I appreciate your help and it feels like it is the right direction (that is why I gave it a plus one) but I already had scope declared. Something is still missing unfortunately.